# Creating Blank Images in Python (allowing pixel by pixel manipulation)

Tags: python, image-processing, image-manipulation, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have this code here that creates a Tkinter Canvas widget, then embeds an image within it.

```
import Tkinter
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class image_manip(Tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.configure(bg='red')

        self.ImbImage = Tkinter.Canvas(self, highlightthickness=0, bd=0, bg='blue')
        self.ImbImage.pack()

        self.i = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r'test.png'))
        self.ImbImage.create_image(150, 100, image=self.i)


def run():
    image_manip().mainloop()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

I'd like to be able to create a blank image within the Canvas widget, so that I could do pixel by pixel manipulation within the widget. How would one go about this?

Comment: Do exactly the same thing as you're doing in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847706/using-pils-imagedraw-module, except use `Image.new` instead of `Image.open`.

Comment: Yes, it indeed did. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To create a new blank image (rather than opening one), you can use the `Image.new(...)` method in place of your `Image.open(...)`.  It is described in [The Image Module](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111190821id_/http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm).

Then call `self.i.put(...)` to do pixel-by-pixel manipulation.  (`i` is the `PhotoImage` object as in your example.)

Here's some general information on [The Tkinter PhotoImage Class](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112023229id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm).

Comment: Actually here is where Image.new(...) is described: http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm